# Writing stax XML to String

Tags: java, xml, java-io, stax

I am using stax to create XML document that I need for my web app. 
Currently I am creating my XML in a file like this:

```
    XMLOutputFactory factory = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance();
    String output=null;
     try 
     {
             XMLStreamWriter writer = factory.createXMLStreamWriter(
                     new FileWriter("C:\\Junk\\xmlDoc.xml"));
             writer.writeStartDocument();
             writer.writeStartElement("TagName1");
             writer.writeAttribute("AAA", "BBB");
             writer.writeEndElement();
             writer.writeEndDocument();             
             writer.flush();
             writer.close();
     } 
     catch (XMLStreamException e) 
     {
         e.printStackTrace();
     } 
     catch (IOException e) 
     {      
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

But an xml file is not what I want, I need to create my XML in a `String`. 
Unfortunately I can't figure out which `OutputStream` object I need instead of the `FileWriter`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need a `java.io.StringWriter`:

Like `FileWriter` it derives from `Writer` and can be passed to `factory.createXMLStreamWriter`. And once your are done you can turn the written content into a string.

```
StringWriter stringOut = new StringWriter();
XMLStreamWriter writer = factory.createXMLStreamWriter(stringOut);
... // write XML

String output = stringOut.toString();
```